# Which textbook proves that Pr(Touch)≈2×Pr( Probability of In The Money)?

Tags: discussion

What "details or clarity" can re-open [Which textbook proves that $Pr(Touch) \approx 2 \times Pr($Probability of In The Money)?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/36802) please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ask a question, ask it in your own words. It is not good to make users sift through other social media to figure out what is being asked in the first place. A lot of readers will not be familiar with some of the acronyms in the original post.

The question you have posted as well is not edited very well. Users like to see reasonable effort put into questions.